# Check whether a CGI GET parameter exists

Tags: perl, get, cgi, uri

I'm trying to determine whether a `GET` query parameter exists from within a Perl CGI program

Here's my query when`sf` exists:

```
http://server.com/support?page=hello&sf=1
```

Second, here's my query when`sf` does not exist:

```
http://server.com/support?page=hello
```

Here's some pseudo code of what I'd like to accomplish:

```
if (sfVariable does not exist) {
     // process code
}
```

I have tried this with no luck (just printed the variable to ensure we are retrieving it correctly):

```
use CGI;

my $q = CGI->new;
my $sfVar = $q->param('sf');
print $sfVar;
```

EDIT:

Here is where I am at:

```
use CGI;
my $q = CGI->new;
my $page = $q->param('sf');
if(not defined $page){
  print "no sf variable\n";
}
```

And I get an error. Here's the log:

```
[Wed Feb 21 16:39:56.041581 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 6198] [client 111.111.111.111:57878] malformed header from script 'test': Bad header: no sf variable
[Wed Feb 21 16:42:02.146266 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 11150] [client 111.111.111.111:58047] malformed header from script 'test': Bad header: no sf variable
[Wed Feb 21 16:42:11.578022 2018] [cgi:error] [pid 29861] [client 111.111.111.111:58062] End of script output before headers: test
```

Comment: didn't tried your code but, do you `use strict; use warnings;` ? it may help you in the future ;)

Comment: Have you tried running your cgi-script on the command line? `perl -le 'use CGI;my$q=CGI->new;print "$_ = ".$q->param($_) for qw(sf page)' "page=hello&sf=1"`. Try running: `perl your-script.pl "page=hello&sf=1"`. Maybe you see something that helps you find the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `param` method will return `undef` if the given value doesn't exist

You need this

```
my $sf_var = $q->param('sf');

if ( not defined $sf_var ) {
    print "There is no sf parameter\n";
}
```

Comment: OP needs `print $cgi->header('text/plain')` before producing output.

Comment: @Sinan: In this case, `print $q->header('text/plain')`